# Form values not submitting to php mail

Tags: php, forms, email

My problem is as follows:

I have these inputs:

```
<select class="span1 select_rooms" id="zimmern">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="span9 mail" id="email" />
```

And this php code:

```
$success = false;
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? preg_replace( "", "", $_POST['email'] ) : "";
$zimmern = isset( $_POST['zimmern'] ) ? preg_replace( "", "", $_POST['zimmern'] ) : "";
$message = 'Email: '.$senderEmail.'Message: '.$zimmern;'
```

Which HTML Attribute is recognized by the php variables?

Comment: Your inputs need name attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form fields have no `name` attributes. Without them their values are **not** submitted.

```
<select class="span1 select_kids" id="kinder">
```

should be

```
<select class="span1 select_kids" name="kinder" id="kinder">
```

etc.